# I can't seem to calculate with modulus

Tags: javascript, modulus, parseint

Its been a few months since I graduated from a tech school (HS level) for programming, and my JavaScript is a bit rusty.  I'm just trying to calculate Y%X=Z with textbox inputs.  However Z always results in NaN, so I'm assuming my problem is the parsing.

```
<html>
<body>
<b>Y: </b><input type="text" id="numY" /><br>
<b>X: </b><input type="text" id="numX" /><br>
<h2>Y % X = Z</h2>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<h3><p id="demo"></p></h3>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var y=document.getElementById('numY');
var x=document.getElementById('numX');
var z=parseInt(y)%parseInt(x);
var demoP=document.getElementById("demo")
demoP.innerHTML="z=" + z;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` and `y` refer to the `<input>` elements, not to their values:

```
var y = document.getElementById('numY').value;
```

Also, pass the radix/base argument to `parseInt`. You want it to be explicit that you're working in base 10:

```
var z = parseInt(y, 10) % parseInt(x, 10);
```

Comment: thanks, but to clarify; using that method would I still need to use parseInt() within my calculation of Z?

Comment: @BrandonDurst you could use the unary `+` operator to make them integers, if you prefer: `z = +y % +x`

Comment: @BrandonDurst: Using the modulo operator will coerce both inputs into numbers.

Comment: @Blender numbers, but not necessarily integers (and it occurs to me that `+` will do the same. Better to use `|0`)

Comment: @Dave: That'll restrict it to the signed 32-bit range. `parseInt` is the proper tool.